# Pasar n parametros a Values () en la declaracion Insert

Tags: c#, sql

Hola me gustaría saber si existe una forma de pasar varios valores por parámetro a `Values` en `Sql`, osea desde

`string Query = "Insert into PersonasFisicas (Nombre,Numero,Direccion) Values ('" + stringNombre + "','"+ intNumero + "','" + stringDireccion +"')";`

Pasarlo a

`string Query = "Insert into PersonasFisicas (Nombre,Numero,Direccion) Values (variosValores)";`

Donde `variosValores` sería el conjunto de valores que quiero pasar por parámetro, no tengo idea si es posible, agradecería mucho la ayuda.Desde ya gracias

Comment: Para futuras referencias: [leer un poco sobre las inyecciones SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Poderse hacer se puede, pero dudo que la inversión de tiempo en hacerlo merezca la pena. Va a depender de como recibes las variables. Si tenes una lista de variables a insertar (en su arden correcto) o si tienes cada variable con su valor.

No dejas de estar trabajando con un `string` y puedes componerlo como quieras. Por ejemplo

```
string parametros = "'" + stringNombre + "','"+ intNumero + "','" + stringDireccion +"'"
string Query = "Insert into PersonasFisicas (Nombre,Numero,Direccion) 
Values (" + parametros + ')";
```

Si tienes los parámetros en una lista;

```
string parametros="";
for (int i=0;i<lista.Count;i++)
  if(i=0) {
    parametros = "'" + lista[i] + "'";
  } else {
    parametros += ", '" + lista[i] + "'";
  }
string Query = "Insert into PersonasFisicas (Nombre,Numero,Direccion) 
Values (" + parametros + ')";
```

Aunque, recuerda, la forma correcta de construir la sentencia es con el `Parameters.Add` del `SqlCommand`. [Aquí tienes la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Gracias no sabia que se podía colocar la completa sentencia string parametros = "'" + stringNombre + "','"+ intNumero + "','" + stringDireccion +"'"

Answer (score -1):

Seria posible si:

- Si haces la inserción desde un select(Soporta SQLServer) .
  algo como:

```
    INSERT INTOTabla2
    SELECT Nombre, Numero, Direcion 
    FROMTabla1
```

- Lo estas haciendo desde un cliente sql y variosValores es un procedimiento almacenado y te retorna las mismas columnas que tienes en  (Nombre,Numero,Direccion).
- Con Codeigniter  existe un metodo insert_batch() le pasamos el array de los elementos
  y el hacer el recorriro.
- Manualmente hacer el recorrido de un array variosValores  y hacer el insert.

Espero sea de ayuda